# Installing Java on a Virtual Private Server

Tags: java, vps

I have recently managed to get my employer to pay for a vps. I teach and asked the vps provider to enable Perl, Python, Ruby, Tomcat and Java. They've done the first four (really quickly) but have got back to me asking which parts of Java I need.

I think the Java Virtual Machine is a given but what other S/W do I need to get installed? I think by getting the vps I now have the chance to teach Enterprise Java and want to get into Java Message Server and Enterprise patterns. Can I get Glassfish installed or is that a silly question? What about servlets and beans?

Thanks in anticipation

Martin Rowe

Answer (score 2):

If your question is, "Can I get <some piece of software installed>?", you probably need to direct that question to whomever is managing your VPS.  If your question is, "Will <some piece of software> run inside a VPS?", the answer is, generally, yes, provided that your VPS has sufficient memory/CPU/storage resources.

With regards to "what other software do I need to get installed?" I think the answer depends entirely on what you want to do.  E.g., if you're going to install Glassfish, look at the list of it's software requirements and make sure you have everything.

Comment: Abgreed. Voted to close. This is an open question along the line of "I dont know waht I need, do you have a clue?". Can not be finally answered.